# Couldn't save current time in Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to save time of profile updating converted to integer number whenever *banned* option is checked but whenever I look at the database field, *ban_time* is nil.

```
def update
    find_user

    if !params[:banned].nil?
        @user.ban_time = Time.now.to_i
        @user.save
    end

    if @user.update(user_params)
        redirect_to @user, notice: "Profil je uspešno ažuriran."
    else
        render "edit"
    end
end
```

Everything else is saved correctly.

Update: Here are schema and model for user.

**Schema**

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.string   "location"
    t.date     "birthdate"
    t.string   "rank"
    t.boolean  "banned"
    t.text     "bandesc"
    t.boolean  "vip"
    t.integer  "ban_time"
    t.integer  "ban_remaining_days"
    t.integer  "bug_report_time"
  end
```

**Model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

    has_secure_password

    validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]+\Z/},
                            length: { maximum: 10, minimum: 4 }
    validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    validates :password, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50, minimum: 4 }, if: :should_validate_pass?
    validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, if: :should_validate_conf?
    validates :location, presence: true, length: { maximum: 30 }
    validates :banned, presence: true, if: :ban_remaining_days?
    validates :ban_remaining_days, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }, inclusion: { in: 1..365 }, if: :banned?
    validates :bandesc, presence: true, length: { maximum: 200, minimum: 20 }, if: :banned?

    def should_validate_pass?
        new_record? || password.present?
    end

    def should_validate_conf?
        new_record? || password_confirmation.present?
    end

end
```

**Form**

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    <% if @user.errors.any? %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |m| %>
                    <li><%= m %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label "Korisničko ime:" %>
        <%= f.text_field :username, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label "Lokacija:" %>
        <%= f.text_field :location, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label "Datum rođenja:" %><br/>
        <%= f.date_select :birthdate, order: [:day, :month, :year], start_year: 1900, end_year: Time.now.year - 18 %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label "E-mail:" %>
        <%= f.text_field :email, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label "Lozinka:" %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label "Potvrda lozinke:" %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

        <h3>Administratorska podešavanja</h3>

        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label "Rank:" %>
            <%= f.text_field :rank, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label "VIP:" %>
            <%= f.check_box :vip %>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label "Banovanje člana:" %>
            <%= f.check_box :banned %>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label "Razlog:" %>
            <%= f.text_area :bandesc, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label "Vremenski period (dana):" %>
            <%= f.text_field :ban_remaining_days, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

    <div class="submit">
        <%= f.submit button_text, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you show model & schema for User?

Comment: @JohnFeltz Question is updated.

Comment: Thanks.  Put in a debug point and verify that the params hash is correct.

Comment: Why not use a datetime field?

Comment: @MickSharpe Because I have two methods for converting days and hours to seconds so this is easier to write. John - I don't know how to do it but I tried to save params[:banned] as integer to database and every time (even when it's checked) it's 0; I don't understand what's wrong, what type should this checkbox return?

Comment: Can you show the view where the checkbox is defined?  It's obviously not coming through view->controller the way you are expecting it.

Comment: @JohnFeltz I can see from requests in Terminal that I get banned parameter normally, btw, I posted form code too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        <%= f.check_box :banned %>
```

...will return '0' if `false` or '1' if `true`

And there's no `params[:banned]` it's `params[:user][:banned]` or `user_params[:banned]`

So change

```
if !params[:banned].nil?
```

into

```
if user_params[:banned] == '0'
```

Comment: Thanks! I saw in one post here on SO that unchecked check boxes are not even sent (but realized it's wrong when I saw request output) so I thought that checking for nil would do the work.